# Java random numbers not random?

Tags: java, random

I was trying to explain the random number generator in Java to a friend when he kept getting the same numbers every time he ran the program. I created my own simpler version of the same thing and I too am getting the same exact numbers he was getting every time I run the program.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestCode{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       int sum = 0;
       Random rand = new Random(100);
       for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++){
           int num = (rand.nextInt(100)) + 1;
           sum += num;
           System.out.println("Random number:" + num);
       }
       //value never changes with repeated program executions.
       System.out.println("Sum: " + sum); 
   }

}
```

The final five numbers out of the 100 are:

```
40
60
27
56
53
```

Comment: I think is better way use Math.random().

Comment: You're using a constant seed when creating your Random instance. So of course you'll get the same numbers.

Comment: @Gere: what is so magical about `Math.random()` and why is it better than using a Random instance?

Comment: For this case use int num = (int) (Math.random()* 100); It seems better. That's it.

Comment: "Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin" - John von Neumann

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have seeded the random generator with a constant value `100`.  It's deterministic, so that will generate the same values each run.

I'm not sure why you chose to seed it with `100`, but the seed value has nothing to do with the range of values that are generated (that's controlled by other means, such as the call to `nextInt` that you already have).

To get different values each time, use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()) constructor with no arguments, which uses the system time to seed the random generator.

Quoting from the Javadoc for the parameterless `Random` constructor:

> Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed
>   of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct
>   from any other invocation of this constructor.

Quoting the actual code in the parameterless `Random` constructor:

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
   Random rand = new Random(100);
```

You're giving the random number generator the same seed (100) each time you start the program.  Give it something like the output from `System.currentTimeMillis()` and that should give you different numbers for each invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Random number generators are really only pseudo-random. That is, they use deterministic means to generate sequences that appear random given certain statistical criteria.

The `Random(long seed)` constuctor allows you to pass in a seed that determines the sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code to generate a random number from a pool of random numbers.

```
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
double[] rand = new double[500];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    rand[i] = r.nextDouble();
}
double random_number = rand[randomInt];
```